# Can Google Gears be installed for Chrome on Mac OS X Snow Leopard?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, google-chrome, google-gears

Can Google Gears be installed for Google Chrome on Mac OS X Snow Leopard?

Google Chrome is a nice browser (very fast, much less memory intensive than Firefox), but until offline storage for Gmail and other Google services is available I can't make it my default browser.

Update: Wow... Google is *slow* updating their code when they don't care. No support yet for Offline Gmail in Mac OS X Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

I was under the impression that Google Chrome's HTML5 support removed the need for Gears, and that Google's moving towards adapting their services for HTML5 over getting Gears to work in Chrome.

Comment: Thanks for the useful tip.

HTML5 is great and whatnot, but until Gmail, Google Docs and Google Calendar use it for online support, I need Gears.

Comment: I understand the position you're in, I'm in it too. I'm just saying that Gears probably won't ever come for Snow Leopard, as they'll just push out HTML5 support for those products instead.

Comment: Then they better hurry with Offline Gmail HTML5 support. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Google Gears is not available for version greater that 10.5 BUT... here is a way to have it installed!

http://theappleblog.com/2009/09/15/how-to-get-google-gears-working-in-snow-leopard/

> Thankfully, the helpful folks who developed Mailplane have created a hacked installer for Google Gears that skips the version check and allows you to install the program in Snow Leopard. You can pick up the modified installer here. As with any hack, proceed at your own risk, but my own experience has been flawless. Once I installed this version of Gears, Mailplane and Fluid were once again able to take advantage of the offline features of sites like Gmail.

Comment: Hope this will work for you also!

Comment: Didn't know that customized Gears installation package. It indeed installs on Snow Leopard, but then only Safari running in 32bits detects it. Google Chrome doesn't see Gears installed.